# Relacionamentos de Tabelas e Bancos de Dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebase

É uma pergunta simples, o que é restrição de integridade dos relacionamentos. 
Por favor me ajuda, eu tenho um TCC pra daqui 1 semana e não acabei essa coisa ainda :'(

Answer (score 0):

*"Restrições de integridade são usados para garantir a exatidão e a consistência dos dados em uma Banco de dados relacional."*

Temos alguns tipos de restrições, como a Restrição de Integridade Referencial que diz que uma chave estrangeira (no caso de uma tabela) tem que ter relação direta com a chave primária que está na tabela pai (a outra tabela que se relaciona com a tabela da chave estrangeira).

> Ou seja, não só deve existir o atributo (campo) nas tabelas, como também, o valor
>   referenciado.

Esse vídeo no youtube do Bóson Treinamentos fala exatamente do que você necessita.

[Modelagem de Dados - Restrições de Integridade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=BurdDn16ZgE)